# In my secure log there is a new group added that I'm unsure about after adding semanage

Tags: centos, security, logs, group

I installed `semanage` onto my `CentOS 6.2` box and I was going through my secure log after the install and noticed this entry:

```
Aug 31 22:12:17 xxxx groupadd[12929]: group added to /etc/group: name=cgred, GID=489
Aug 31 22:12:17 xxxx groupadd[12929]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=cgred
Aug 31 22:12:17 xxxx groupadd[12929]: new group: name=cgred, GID=489
```

I couldn't find any info on the group `cgred` I did find [this Arch Linux Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups) about Control Groups, is that what this is?

Just looking for info to make sure I know what is going on with my box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This group is created by the `libcgroup` package, which is indeed an API for control groups.